# Ubuntu Disk isn't showing up at Boot

Tags: macos, ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, disk-utility

I recently installed ubuntu on a flash drive, following all of the instructions on the ubuntu website.

When I started up my mac, it didn't appear in the boot menu. Has this happened to anyone else here booting their thumb drives onto their macs? If so, what did you do to fix this?

Comment: It'd help if you posted the exact hardware you have and what guide you've been following.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the EFI-bios-thing macs use nowadays has a setting menu you can access by hitting some button just after boot. Then you should be able to change the boot priorities to favour booting from usb connected devices before attempting to boot from the hard drive.

Comment: There is a method of showing all available devices, but it isn't showing. How can I do what you say?

Comment: Nevermind, according to [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1948) I'm wrong in assuming Apple lets you do anything obviously possible.

Answer (score 0):

[rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net) needs to be installed for it to work.